# Can I use photos on my personal google drive account for my business website?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

Hi I am thinking of images that are used on my website on to the public folder of my google drive account and access it using `<img src="some.gdrive.link.com">`. Can I use google drive in such way for my business site?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and this has been answered before on stackexchange, here's a copy of the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34994471/7483211)

Use the 'Get Link' option in Google Drive to get the URL.

Use  tag in HTML and paste the link in there.

Change Open? in the URL to uc?.

Comment: You are correct but can I use it for business purpose?

Comment: @uneet7 According to the terms of service only personal use allowed. But I would be very surprised if they would complain if you use it for minor business purpose.